# php dynamic number array add missing values defined by a range

Tags: php, arrays, range

I have looked and googled many times I found a few posts that are simular but I can not find the answer Im looking for so I hope you good people can help me.

I have a function that returns a simple number array. The array number values are dynamic and will change most frequently.

e.g.

```
array(12,19,23)
```

What I would like to do is take each number value in the array, compare it to a set range and return all the lower value numbers up to and including the value number in the array.

So if I do this:

```
$array = range(
    (11,15),
    (16,21),
    (22,26)
);
```

The Desired output would be:

```
array(11,12,16,17,18,19,22,23)
```

But instead I get back all the numbers in all the ranges.

```
array(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26)
```

What would be a simple solution to resolve this?

Comment: you missing your first array in parameter ?

Comment: I just wanted to add that the array Im working with has NO keys only values so looks like this: array(121923) so when returned should look like: array(1112161718192223) because its then passed to another function which compares the result to a data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$range = array(
            array(11,15),
            array(16,21),
            array(22,26),
);

$array = array(12,19,23);
$result = array();
foreach($range as $key=>$value)
{
    //$range1 =$range[$key];
    $min = $range[$key][0];
    $max = $range[$key][1];
    for($i = $min;$i<=$max;$i++)
    {
        if($i <= $array[$key])
        {
            array_push($result,$i);
        }
    }

}
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for all your answers they all worked very well but I have to choose one and the reason for choosing this one is that the code had to go inside a function and this answer seems to do the trick. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each element, find the the start and end values you need to include, and append them to the output array:

```
$a = array(12,19,23);
$b = array(
    range(11,15),
    range(16,21),
    range(22,26)
);

$c = array();
foreach ($a as $k => $cap) {
    $start = $b[$k][0];
    $finish = min($b[$k][count($b[$k])-1], $cap);
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $finish; $i++) {
        $c[] = $i;
    }
}
print_r($c);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 17
    [4] => 18
    [5] => 19
    [6] => 22
    [7] => 23
)
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 5 seconds, though I am curious as to whether yours runs faster. Both appear to be O(n²) but mine has more function calls in the loops.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6, it is not O(n^2), it would be O(n*r) where r is the maximum range specified by the input. If one of the ranges was (1, 1000000) then that would almost certainly dominate

Comment: Wow people you guys are very quick to answer thank you very much. Seems im spoilt for choice but I will try all the answers asap.

Comment: just a quick note this answer works inside the function aswell but I cant choose two answers or I would :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is probably not the most efficient, but here goes:

```
$numbers = array(12,19,23);

$ranges = array(
    array(11,15),
    array(16,21),
    array(22,26)
);

$output = array();

// Loop through each of the numbers and ranges:

foreach($numbers as $num) {
    foreach($ranges as $r) {
        if ($num >= $r[0] && $num <= $r[1]) {
            // This is the correct range
            // Array merge to append elements
            $output = array_merge($output, range($r[0], $num));
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Sort the numbers if you wish
sort($output, \SORT_NUMERIC);

print_r($output);
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 17
    [4] => 18
    [5] => 19
    [6] => 22
    [7] => 23
)
```

Comment: I didn't think that it would take an entire day to test my answer, but glad to know that it also works. :-P